# Election vote count bar graph with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I've got some simple election data:

```
library(tidyverse)

District_4 <- tibble("Year" = c(2012, 2014, 2016),
                     "Republican Votes" = c(128568, 84815, 165796),
                     "Democrat Votes" = c(102222, 51357, 89141),
                     "Independent Votes" = c(0, 9246, 0))
```

I'm trying to create a bar graph (with ggplot) of each election year, with total vote count by party on the y-axis and `Year` on the x-axis. I want to have the vote counts by party grouped in 3 columns (Rep, Dem, Ind), and this can be facetted by election year or not. Or if it is easier to stack (with a `position = "fill"`, then I'm cool with that, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you started

```
library(tidyverse)
District_4 %>%
    mutate(Year = as.Date(paste0(Year, "/01/01"))) %>%
    gather(key, VoteCount, -Year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, VoteCount, fill = key)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Or to have columns side-by-side (rather than stacked), you can use `position = "dodge2"` inside `geom_bar`

```
District_4 %>%
    mutate(Year = as.Date(paste0(Year, "/01/01"))) %>%
    gather(key, VoteCount, -Year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, VoteCount, fill = key)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2")
```

[image]

---

### Update

To manually set colours

```
District_4 %>%
    mutate(Year = as.Date(paste0(Year, "/01/01"))) %>%
    gather(key, VoteCount, -Year) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Year, VoteCount, fill = key)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge2") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(
        "Democrat Votes" = "grey",
        "Republican Votes" = "orange",
        "Independent Votes" = "purple"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks I really appreciate it! Where did the `VoteCount` come from? Through a `mutate()` function I presume?

Comment: @papelr `VoteCount` comes from spreading from wide to long: `gather(key, VoteCount, -Year)`.

Comment: OHHHH I see now

Comment: @papelr Yes. I've made an edit to my answer to show an example.